# cat /usr/share/dict/words > words.txt "No Space Left On Device"

Tags: unix, dictionary

I am trying to use that dictionary file on Unix but every time I use the command: 
cat /usr/share/dict/words > words.txt

I get the message "No Space Left On Device". Has anyone else gotten this message and figured out a solution? I have searched around and haven't found anything.

I am working on a school server and I typed df -H to find out that I haven't even come close to using my available space so there has to be something else going on.

Output of `df` command--->

```
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/misc/guest 11G 3.6G 6.3G 37% /home/guest 
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/majors 146G 139G 0 100% /home/majors
/dev/sda2 40631988 1703356 36831348 5% / 
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv01 203147960 22470992 170191208 12% 
/scratch4 /dev/sda7 4061540 74260 3777636 2% /tmp 
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv00 314879212 251729436 46898256 85% /backup 
/dev/sda6 10153988 839452 8790420 9% /var 
/dev/sda5 20315812 10550172 8717000 55% /usr 
/dev/sda1 101086 37382 58485 39% /boot tmpfs 4088804 0 4088804 0% /dev/shm
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/faculty 442383104 391954976 27655936 94% /home/faculty
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/grads 121892608 84729120 30892608 74% /home/grads   
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/courses 75325152 62762560 8689952 88% /home/courses  
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/misc/research 18283264 8096928 9242784 47% /home/research 
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/misc/contest 15481856 892352 13803072 7% /home/contest 
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/staff 14982144 4206688 10002176 30% /home/staff
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/misc/guest 10157376 3507552 6125664 37% /home/guest
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/majors 142203584 134866176 0 100% /home/majors 
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/class 30472192 2391424 26508096 9% /home/class 
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/sait 49580256 8202944 38818144 18% /home/sait 
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/system 298754432 238142048 45192416 85% /home/system
```

Comment: What is the output of `pwd`?

Comment: My pwd is /home/majors/last_name

Comment: Please add the output of `df` to your question,it's very tough to guess/come out with any idea without that!

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to get this in a good format.

Comment: nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/misc/guest
                        11G   3.6G   6.3G  37% /home/guest
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/majors
                       146G   139G      0 100% /home/majors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So,your claim that your hard disk is empty enough to accommodate those list of dictionary words was not `true`!

See,the output of `df` in second line says

```
nfs.cs.fsu.edu:/home/majors 146G 139G 0 100% /home/majors  # 0 GB of space available...
```

that you have 100% of /home/majors partition filled,there is 0 GB of space left,against your thought!!!

The only step in such a case is to delete some of the files which are unnecessary from `/home/majors` partition!

Comment: You're absolutely right about that. I made a mistake. I would delete some of the files, but I do not believe I have access to do that.

Comment: Sorry! Thank you very much for your help! It was greatly appreciated. At least I know the source of the problem.

Comment: @MipsMoreLikeWhips-You shouldn't mention SORRY for any reason over here! There was nothing like such to beg pardon! I am happy that at least I helped you out! CHEERS and continue helping students of `FSU`...

Answer (score 1):

Using `df -H .` will show the free disk space on the partition hosting the current directory, and makes easier to see where you are trying to write data.

Your `df` command shows that there's free space, but not on the partition you are trying to write to.

Comment: Hmmm, if that is the only area I am allowed to work in, then I am out of luck right?